# Please check the front,top and left hand side view of my figure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

[image]

Below is the link what I have tried

[image]

Please check if it is correct or not?

Comment: So last time you were asked to edit your post to include the images - perhaps you should that on this one. See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/35528/10902

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top ,Side And Front view of this object](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35528/top-side-and-front-view-of-this-object)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. The isometric drawing and views you have been asked to provide.*

[image]

*Figure 2. A bad answer.*

While the original image is missing a couple of dimensions to draw it accurately your attempt has some gross errors.

Item (1) seems to be mirrored and badly proportioned. Your views show slots at (2) and (3) where you can see straight through the model. If this was correct there would be a great big '**+**' slot visible on the other view. There is no slot on the isometric drawing.

This excercise is really simple.

1. Draw what an observer at Figure 1, (1) would see. Use dotted lines for hidden edges.
2. Draw what an obersver at Figure 1, (2) would see. There are no hidden edges in this view.
3. Draw what an observer at Figure 1, (3) would see. I'll leave you to figure out if there are hidden edges.

Edit your question and post the results. Please also delete your previous question on this subject if you haven't already done it. The rule on SE is to *fix* your question if it has been closed. Don't open another one.

Comment: I'm not getting exactly how to draw this.Can you provide your answer please?

Comment: There is no point in me providing an answer as you will learn very little from it. Can you make a model of the object using the isometric drawing? Use modelling clay, cardboard, Lego or whatever you have available. Then take a photo from directions 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: By seeing your answer ,I can learn the concepts and way of doing such questions.

Comment: You can learn that from a book. You seem to be having great difficulty in visualising the problem so I think that making a simple model is best. If you don't want to then, I'm afraid, I am not willing to help further.